# How to refer to PART_XXX

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

Having mocked up a custom control as a window and got all the behaviour right, I'm now trying to turn it into a proper custom control (called "When", it's a date-time widget).

I have prepared a When.XAML file in which sub-elements are named PART_xxx

```
<ResourceDictionary
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:glob="clr-namespace:System.Globalization;assembly=mscorlib"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Widgets">
  <local:DatePartPositionValueConverter x:Key="DatePartPositionValueConverter" />
  <local:DatePartVisibilityValueConverter x:Key="DatePartVisibilityValueConverter" />
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:When}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:When}">
          <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource 
                {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}">
              <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,0,0,0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition />
                  ...
                  <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock x:Name="PART_year" Grid.Column="{Binding 
                    Converter={StaticResource DatePartPositionValueConverter}, 
                    ConverterParameter=y}">
                  <TextBlock.Text>
                  ...
```

The custom control project Generic.XAML file references When.XAML

```
<ResourceDictionary
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/Widgets;component/Themes/When.xaml" />
  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

My code, however, does not seem to be able to resolve the PART_ names.

I'd like to be able to compare _focussedElement to (eg) PART_year to provide context for validation checks. It must be possible to refer directly to PART_xxx from the code of a custom control, otherwise it would be impossible to use code to bind event handlers to the elements of a template.

What have I failed to apprehend?

---

To paraphrase and expand on the excellent answer below, PART_year *isn't* in scope because there's no opportunity for the IDE's code generation magic to bring it into scope. So you bring it into scope yourself, like this:

```
MenuItem PART_MenuItemToday, PART_MenuItemNow, 
  PART_MenuItemMonthEnd, PART_MenuItemMonthStart;
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
  base.OnApplyTemplate();
  PART_MenuItemMonthEnd = GetTemplateChild("PART_ContextMenuMonthEnd") as MenuItem;
  PART_MenuItemMonthEnd.Click += PART_ContextMenuMonthEnd_Click;
  ...
}
```

When you need to hook the same set of handlers to several widgets you can do this

```
private void BindGenericHandlers(TextBlock textBlock)
{
  textBlock.GotFocus += PART_GotFocus;
  textBlock.LostFocus += PART_LostFocus;
  textBlock.MouseDown += PART_MouseDown;
  textBlock.MouseEnter += PART_MouseEnter;
  textBlock.MouseLeave += PART_MouseLeave;
}

TextBlock _focussedElement, PART_year, PART_month, PART_day, PART_hour, PART_minute, PART_second, PART_designator;

public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
  base.OnApplyTemplate();
  BindGenericHandlers(PART_day = GetTemplateChild("PART_day") as TextBlock);
  BindGenericHandlers(PART_designator = GetTemplateChild("PART_designator") as TextBlock);
  BindGenericHandlers(PART_hour = GetTemplateChild("PART_hour") as TextBlock);
  BindGenericHandlers(PART_minute = GetTemplateChild("PART_minute") as TextBlock);
  BindGenericHandlers(PART_month = GetTemplateChild("PART_month") as TextBlock);
  BindGenericHandlers(PART_second = GetTemplateChild("PART_second") as TextBlock);
  BindGenericHandlers(PART_year = GetTemplateChild("PART_year") as TextBlock);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You retreive references to your PARTs in the code by using the `GetTemplateChild` method inside the `OnApplyTemplate` override.  So in the code for your control, you'll have the following:

```
private const string PART_TEXTINPUT = "PART_TEXT";
private TextBox _textInput;

public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
   base.OnApplyTemplate();
   _textInput = GetTemplateChild(PART_TEXTINPUT) as TextBox;
}
```

Since you are using PARTs, you seem to be making a lookless control, and therefore, you can't have a direct reference to the element from the XAML (since a custom `ControlTemplate` could replace it with something unexpected).  So you retrieve references to your PARTs with the `GetTemplateChild` method.

NOTE: Be sure to use the lowest possible type for the part (in your code) in case someone replaces your expected control with a different implementation.

Comment: +1 - Yes, I am making a lookless control. I know you can't refer directly, there's no opportunity for the code generation that the IDE normally does, and this conbined with the need to bind event handlers had me very puzzled. Your answer is *exactly* what I was looking for.

Comment: Is it possible to create a 'lookful' custom control other than as a UserControl derivative?

Comment: Say more about what you're trying to accomplish, Peter.  You can derive directly from an existing control, e.g. `public class CustomTextBox : TextBox`.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: Another note - you may want to look at the `TemplatePart` attribute as a way of informing those using your control what PARTs they should be aware of.

Comment: Thanks to your assistance I've already accomplished the original goal, which was build a lookless date-time widget derived from Control and using composition. Now I'm just generally pushing back the bounds of my ignorance. You haven't misunderstood anything, I've expanded the scope of my curiosity.